# Vim insert mode file path completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I want to change where vim looks for file completion, but only in insert mode.  For example:

I open gvim inside of the `CG-Website` directory.

This is my directory structure:

[image]

Then i go in to the css folder and open `style.css`

[image]

using `:e src/static/css/style.css`

Now i am inside of style.css and i want to complete a file name that is down one directory.

I want to be able to type `../` in `INSERT` mode and have all the files/folders that are inside of the static folder show up, instead of the `www` folder which is what it does right now.

However I don't want to change the actual directory, because I still want `:e` to work normally.

Comment: I just noticed (by editing your question for better format) that, your current dir is `CG-We..` then of course `../` won't work as you expected. you said  you do **not** want to change your CWD.... the only way I can see is...the `CtrlP` plugin.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the format, i appreciate it.  I was hoping there was some way to change it so that file name completion starts from the directory of the current file, instead of the current directory.  Perhaps there isn't?

Comment: Yes it could be done, if you have `autochdir` set. but you said you don't want to change the current dir. You just give `ctrlp` a try. It allows you to fuzzyfind file/dirs under your root (project root) dir.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I wanted.  I want it to work by using a popup window while im typing in INSERT mode and press <c-f>

Answer (score 4):

Insert mode filename completion is always done from the "current directory" or "working directory" which may or may not be the directory of the current file. Since you don't want to change directories, filename completion *can't* work like you want it to work.

Actually, the last sentence of `:h compl-filename` should give you a hint:

```
Search for the first file name that starts with the
same characters as before the cursor.  The matching
file name is inserted in front of the cursor.
Alphabetic characters and characters in 'isfname'
are used to decide which characters are included in
the file name.  Note: the 'path' option is not used
here (yet).
```

One solution to this problem is to `set autochdir` so that Vim always changes the working directory to the directory of the current file and use a plugin like [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) (there are others) for navigation. When configured properly, CtrlP lets you navigate your files from your project's home as defined by the presence of a `.git` or similar directory. This is *really* handy.

However, you can get around that limitation relatively easily with `set autochdir` (again, you *need* it for filename completion to work like you -- and I -- want it to work) and a bit of creativity:

```
nnoremap <F9> :e ~/path/to/project/
```

Consider this mapping as a quick shortcut to your project.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `autochdir`, I was having some issues with some plugin or other caching my previous working directory such that my `:e <TAB>`-ing was in the wrong directory.  `set autochdir` has fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are approaching this the wrong way. You want to filter results relative to your last opened dir without changing your current dir and that doesn't quite make sense.

My recommendation is to use a tool what will allow you to quickly filter through all of your files from the root folder of your project.

Take a look at [Command-T: Fast file navigation for VIM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025)

PS: you need vim with ruby support for that.